# Lost residence permit in Austria - can you leave the country and return?

Tags: resident-permit

My sister has a visa for studies in Austria and she lost her permit residence document as well as other documents, but she still has her passeport. She filled the lost report at the police station and tomorrow she will ask for a duplicate of the permit residence. The problem is that she needs to come home to Morocco before the duplicate will be ready. She needs to know if there is any possibility that she can come to Morocco with any other type of travel document.

Comment: As I know, in such cases you must to contact embassy or consulte to get a temporary passport.

Comment: She won't need the permanent residence card to leave Austria (or enter Morocco). She'll need it to return to Austria. Will the replacement need her physical presence to pick it up for security purposes? If not, is there somebody reliable that she can trust to check her post and send the document to Morocco? Is there anyway she can forego the Morocco trip or postphone it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Travel.SE